# How to conditionally set specific class property with angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class, ng-style

I have 1 div in which I want to conditionally set background color property of this class. I am using [boostrap progress bar](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_progressbars.asp) and I want to use below class only because it contains some custom settings for progress bar.

Below is my div:

```
.statistics .progress-bar {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: width 0.6s ease 0s;
    width: 0;
}




 <div class="statistics" ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70"
                                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{'width' : ( item.statistics + '%' )}">
     </div>
  </div>
```

Condition is like below :

```
If statistics > 100
    backgroundcolor=red;
else 
    backgroundcolor=black;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using simple expression

```
ng-style="<condition> ? { <true-value> } : { <false-value> }"
```

---

**Output**

[image: Updated Output]

**Code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-controller="myCtrl">

        <div ng-style="item.statistics > 100 ? { 'background-color':'red', 'width': item.statistics + '%' }: { 'background-color':'yellow', 'width': item.statistics + '%'}">
            <h2>$scope.statistics = {{statistics}}</h2>
        </div>

        <div ng-style="item.statistics2 > 100 ? { 'background-color':'red', 'width': item.statistics2 + '%' } : { 'background-color':'yellow', 'width': item.statistics2 + '%'}">
            <h2>$scope.statistics2 = {{statistics2}}</h2>
        </div>

        <script>
            var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

            myApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
                $scope.item = {};
                $scope.item.statistics = 30;
                $scope.item.statistics2 = 101;
            }]);
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: I tried like this but getting error:ng-style="{'width' : ( item.statistics + '%' ),item.statistics > 100 ? { 'background-color':'a08bcd' } : { 'background-color':'#c1f3ca' }}".Syntax Error: Token '.' is unexpected, expecting [}]

Comment: @Learning **Please see my updated code** as per your latest requirements. `As you can see, the background color as well as the width is also dynamic`. I'm sure it will work for you now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-class to set dynamically css classes

```
.statistics .progress-bar {
   background-color: black;
   border-radius: 10px;
   line-height: 20px;
   text-align: center;
   transition: width 0.6s ease 0s;
   width: 0;
   color: black
}

.red {
   color: red
}

<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
     aria-valuenow="70"
     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
     ng-style="{'width' : ( item.statistics + '%' )}"
     ng-class="{ red: item.statistics > 100 }"
>
```

If you don't want to create extra classes, you can use ng style :

```
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" 
    aria-valuenow="70"
    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" 
    ng-style="getItemStyle(item)">
```

Then in your controller, you have to create the getItemStyle function :

```
 $scope.getItemStyle = function(item) {
     // determine the color
     var itemColor = item.statistics > 100 ? 'red' : 'black';
     // return object containing the css props
     return {
        'width': item.statistics + '%',
        'color': itemColor
     };
 };
```

Comment: What if i want to set 2 or more colors then i have to create that many classes for that

Comment: yes and you can add conditions to ng-class, i.e ng-class="{ green: item.statistics < 50, red: item.statistics > 100} for example

Comment: sorry but i dont want to create an extra class just for setting color property.instead i would like to update existing class background color property only

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ng-style](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle) for changin background property
or [ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) for class manipulation.

Do not forget to use object notation like this

```
data-ng-class = {'test-class': condition}
```